# Best statistical model to compare student metrics

Tags: z-score, method-comparison

I want to understand what would be the best statistical model to use if I'm comparing students basis their metrics that carry a certain weightage. Details are as below

Metric (Weightage)
% of assignments completed (10%) - format (%) 
% feedback received from teachers (10%) - format (%) 
number of assignments completed (10%) - format (number)
average attendance in days (10%) - format (number) 
quality of projects submitted (40%) - format (%)
projects (20%) format (%)

Since this data is spread across percentages & time, what would be the best way to put it on one scale for evaluation ?

Comment: Is there a reason why the weights don't add up to 100? Is higher always better here?

Comment: Oh the rest 20% is for practicals. It's added later but we can put that too in here

Comment: Have you considered turning each variable into a rank/percentile and applying the weights to those?